# Image recognition and database, where do I start?

Tags: android, database, image-processing

I was thinking to do a phone app for a card game (MtG). It would allow the user to use the phone camera as a scanner, and once the card is within sight, it detects it, seeks the corresponding card info in a database, and adds it to the user collection.

I know it is an ambitious project, maybe too much, and don't know exactly where to start. I have been coding for two years in C and C++ in my CS courses, but I never had any phone app programming experience. It would be designed for Android as a priority, as from what I understood, programming for iOs seems to be rather troublesome, and I already had some experience with Java. But of course, if there is way to make it run on both Os, it would be ideal.

I think I have identified the three main parts of my project: having an algorythm that can recognize when there is a card in front of him, analyze the data on the card ( Name, cost, edition ect. thanks to the serial number?), and try to find it in a database, which leads me to the second part, having a database that can be edited. The thirdpart is to have this user database saved on a server, just not localy. However, I don't think this last one is the most important one.

I was wondering if you share any advice,past experience, useful software, githubs, similiar projects or recommended lectures or videos.

Sorry for the messy English, it's not my first language, and thank you for your help!

Comment: question is too broad to ask, please specify exact problem would be great idea to take help, will recommend to find some tutorials and then if any specific problem then please ask.

Answer (score 0):

The app which you planning to build is basically related to Machine Learning(like scanning Image identifying text). I will Suggest you to take a look at [ML Kit for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/)